# JQuery toggle function hides when it should alternate handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have [this](http://jsfiddle.net/6sNgK/).

```js
$(function()
 {
    $("#test_div").toggle(
        function() { $("#test_div").css({"background-color": "#00ff00"}); },
        function() { $("#test_div").css({"background-color": "#0000ff"}); }
    );
});
```

According to the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-even/), every time I click in the div the functions in toggle should execute in an alternate way. First the function in the first argument should execute and after the second click the function in the second argument should execute.

However, the div just hides. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you are using jQuery 1.9.0 or later, they removed the toggle event. Try with toggleClass().

Comment: Oh. I just noticed. It says that in the documentation page. The problem was actually from some old code we had. Thanks. You should make this an answer and not just a comment.

Comment: Forget about `css` method at all in favor of `addClass`, `removeClass` and `toggleClass`. This will make your code much more cleaner and unobtrusive.

Comment: @dfsq, Thanks for the answer. I actually know that, but I made this quick and dirty example just to show the problem I had.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using jQuery 1.9.0 or later, they removed the toggle event. Try with toggleClass().

Answer (score 2):

use [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/). create a class with the background you want and toggle it.. simple and readable..:)

try this

**JQUERY**

```
 $("#test_div").click(function(){
     $(this).toggleClass("newClass");
 });
```

**CSS**

```
 #test_div
 {
   background-color: #ff0000;
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
 }
 #test_div.newClass
 {
   background-color: #0000ff;
 }
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/6sNgK/3/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I actually know that, but I made this quick and dirty example just to show the problem I had.

Answer (score 0):

This functionality of `.toggle` was removed in jQuery 1.9, and with good cause.  It's fairly simple to maintain state of the item you want to toggle internally, perhaps like this:

```
$("#test_div").on('click', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.css('background-color') == '#00ff00') {
        $this.css('background-color', '#0000ff');
    }
    else {
        $this.css('background-color', '#00ff00');
    }
});
```

If that's no good you can just use a `.data` param like "toggleState," which is probably a better idea since you can't depend on an accurate reading from `.css`.

Comment: Perfect example why `css` method should not be used - makes code obtrusive and hard to maintain.

Comment: @dfsq I updated my answer to specify that using data to track state would be preferred

Answer (score 0):

Try to use like this

```
$(function()
 {
    $("#test_div").click(
function() { 
            if ($("#test_div").css("background-color") == "rgb(0, 255, 0)")
                $("#test_div").css({"background-color": "#0000ff"});
            else
                $("#test_div").css({"background-color": "#00ff00"});
            }
    );
});
```

[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Dineshkani/6sNgK/2/)